# What can be an alternative to plain polling in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, polling

I am developing a bidding app in RoR when every auction has an expiry date and time. I am conceptually stuck in expiring the ongoing auctions. The problem is, I have to serve a list of ongoing auctions to the bidder. Somehow I need to discard the expired auctions show only the ongoing ones.

One approach is, prior to serving the list, inspect the expiry date and time for each of the auctions and filter out the expired ones there itself. That's going to introduce a performance overhead for sure.

Second approach is to poll the list of auctions at a very short interval, say a minute or so, and flag the expired ones with an `expired` bit in DB. This is even worse.

How can I play smart here?

Comment: Can you post the database structure for the expired fields? And the code you're using to poll/query?

Comment: I haven't coded the poll it, that was a thought

Comment: So, since this is an auction site, do the auctions have some kind of 'extend the expiration by XX time if someone bids within XX time of expiration'?

Comment: Can you edit and post a couple of examples of what you're thinking about in these different scenarios? Even psuedo code would be easier to talk about than just the description of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary where the keys are the expiry times and the values are references to the relevant auctions. When you start an auction, you can calculate that auction's end time and place it in the dictionary accordingly. Later you can simply check the dictionary for any entries for the current time instead of scanning the list of all auctions.

Comment: This won't work. By the time I access, some auctions might already have expired. Those will not be mapped to bucket in the dictionary key-ed by the end time.

Comment: I imagine auctions expire every integer second. You should be able to map them in under a second. If you're worried about crawling through large buckets just use more buckets... That said, you can in fact check the dictionary for references which will expire _any_ number of arbitrary seconds in the future. I.e. at 13:10:15 check which expire on 13:11:15 and add any to a "short list"; you can then reduce your polling (for auctions which expire at _current_ time to be ended) to just this short list.